# elegant way of preparing a string from hash values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

below is the hash I have

```
my_hash = {
  "unique_id": [
    {
      "code": "1001",
      "message": "The unique id has already been taken."
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to prepare a string from the value of above hash. Ex.
`"1001-The unique id has already been taken."`

So far I am able to get the result with below

```
my_hash.values.flatten.map {|a| a.values.join('-')}.join(',')
```

I want to know is there any way of doing this in a better way.

Update: `my_hash` can have multiple hash values.

`{"unique_id":[{"code":"1001","message":"The unique id has already been taken."}], "user_id":[{"code":"1002","message":"The user id has already been taken."}]}`

And expects value `"1001-The unique id has already been taken.,1002-The user id has already been taken."`

Comment: Updated expected string @CarySwoveland

Comment: One does not normally include quotes with symbols unless they are needed (as when a symbol is formed from more than one word: `:"my dog saffi"`). `"code": "1001"`, `code: "1001"`, `:"code" => "1001"` and `:code => "1001"` are all equivalent.

Comment: @CarySwoveland even if the hash is `{:unique_id=>[{:code=>"1001", :message=>"The unique id has already been taken."}], :user_id=>[{:code=>"1002", :message=>"The user id has already been taken."}]}` how can shorten my ugly looking code?

Comment: What is the expected output if you have multiple errors for the same attribute?

Answer (score 1):

here is a shorter version:

```
my_hash[:unique_id].first.values.join("-")
```

Comment: I update my hash comment @Camillle. Hash can have multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_hash = {"unique_id":[{"code":"1001","message":"The unique id has already been taken"}],"user_id":[{"code":"1002","message":"The user id has already been taken"}]} 


my_hash.flat_map {|k,v| v.map(&:values).join '-'}.to_sentence
```

or

```
my_hash.flat_map {|k,v| v.map(&:values).join '-'}.join ','
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_hash = {"unique_id":[{"code":"1001","message":"The unique id has already been taken."}], "user_id":[{"code":"1002","message":"The user id has already been taken."}]}

my_hash.values.map{|v| v.map{|a| "#{a[:code]}-#{a[:message]}"}}.flatten.join(",")
```